# How can I reload my Neovim config written in lua with a shortcut?

Tags: lua, config, neovim

I want to reload my `neovim` configuration files with just a couple of keystrokes instead of having to restart the app. I was able to do this when using an `init.vim` with the following command:

```
nnoremap <leader>sv <cmd>source $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

`$MYVIMRC` points correctly to my config entry point.

The problem is that I switched to using `lua`, and now I can't do the same. I have read the docs and tried variants of the following without success:

```lua
util.nnoremap("<leader>sv", "<cmd>luafile $MYVIMRC<CR>")
```

Finally, I found a solution doing this:

```lua
function load(name)
    local path = vim.fn.stdpath('config') .. '/lua/' .. name .. '.lua'
    dofile(path)
end

load('plugins')
load('config/mapping')
load('lsp/init')
```

Which is buggy and feels wrong.

Is there any way to do this? I read the example in `vimpeccable`, but I want to see the other available options since I would rather not install another plugin.

I know that `plenary` includes a function to reload modules, but I don't understand how to use it. A complete example of that would be good too since I already use `plenary` in my config.

Answer (score 1):

I am a new Neovim user, so I guess my solution may not work for some edge cases.

This function flushes the module of current buffer:

```lua
local cfg = vim.fn.stdpath('config')
Flush = function()
    local s = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
    if string.match(s, '^' .. cfg .. '*') == nil then
        return
    end
    s = string.sub(s, 6 + string.len(cfg), -5)
    local val = string.gsub(s, '%/', '.')
    package.loaded[val] = nil
end
```

You can call it whenever you write to a buffer with this autocommand:

```
autocmd BufWrite *.lua,*vim call v:lua.Flush()
```

This way, after you execute `:source $MYVIMRC` it will also reload changed Lua modules.

Comment: we need reload for an entire folder, not just a single file.